# Estou usando a versão 5.1 do laravel

Tags: php

Estou usando a versão 5.1 do laravel e não consigo validar os dados, esse seria o erro:

FatalThrowableError na linha 32 de ValidatesRequests.php :
Erro de tipo: O argumento 1 passado para App \ Http \ Controllers \ Controller :: validate () deve ser uma instância de Illuminate \ Http \ Request, array fornecido, chamado em / mnt / c / Users / igarcia / PhpstormProjects / curso / app / Http / Controllers / painel / ProduutosController.php na linha 46

E o meu controller está assim:

public function store(Request $request)
{

```
    $dados = $request->all();

    $this->validate($dados, professor::$rules);

    professor::create($dados);

    return redirect('/professor');
}
```

e o model está assim:

'required|min:3|max:150',
        'idade' => 'required|min:1|max:3',
        'email' => 'required|min:10|max:40',
        'cargo' => 'required|min:5|max:40',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed',];
}

Comment: `$this->validate` não suporta array, você passou o all() nele, e o all() é um array, para usar arrays no validador tem que usar o método `Validator::make($dados, professor::$rules)` (com `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;`)

Comment: Boa tarde. Troque o código para `$this->validate($request, professor::$rules)`. Como o @GuilhermeNascimento mencionou, `validate` espera `Request`, e não um `array` como parâmetro.

Comment: valeu familia, estou iniciando em larável 5.1, essa dica valeu demais, obrigado;